# How to test for unused / orphaned HTML files or links?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have a folder with about 80 HTML files. Is there a way to find out which files are unused? I'm using VS Code.

Comment: What Platform/OS are you on? Find out what command you can use to get a list of HTML files under a directory (such as [`find . -name "*.html"` on UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))), and then pass those paths into a file content search command like `grep` or ripgrep.

Comment: How do you determine if a file is really unused? What if a HTML file, without any incoming links in the same site is actually intended to be only linked-to from other websites or desktop software?

Comment: I'm using WIndows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a number of tools.

Some are listed at https://alt-web.com/TUTORIALS/?id=remove_unused_site_files

Reproduced here from that page:

### Orphan File Checkers

***Xenu Link Sleuth** (Win only) this no-frills, free utility does a number of things well including finding broken links on your web site, creating site maps and more. Don't be deceived by Xenu's small file size (1 MB) or simplicity. It actually works very well.

**Inspyder's OrFind** will  "crawl your site" and identify HTML pages and images that are no longer used.  The software can be configured to automatically delete those files, and it will  even email you a report if any files are modified. This can provide a webmaster  with peace of mind, knowing that if their webspace gets hacked, they'll be  alerted. There is a free trial available. Afterward, you need to pay for the  software to continue using it.

**FindOrphan** is a simple application  created by SobolSoft that will search your local HTML, PHP and ASP files for any  unlinked files, including media files like images and video.

Separately another tool listing:

**Finding orphaned files on websites** - a free github repo tool at.
https://shallowsky.com/blog/tags/weborphan/